# The rear compartment of a vehicle

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Does anyone know if there is a word for the "rear compartment" of a vehicle? I'm talking about larger vehicles, trucks, jeeps, etc. In the particular case I'm dealing with, I'm translating a movie script discussing a World War II era truck (think "Saving Private Ryan") taking soldiers to the front lines. The "rear compartment" (???) is covered on top with canvas, or cloth, and the back of the truck is left open, presumably so that the soldiers can disembark quickly.

Maybe it's just "rear compartment" - I'm not sure.

Comment: The answers you have received so far are correct. However it might be helpful if you wrote the whole of your translated sentence so that we can see the words in context.

Comment: "Back (of the truck)" would also work.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is called "[truck bed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/truck+bed)".

> - the floor or bottom of a wagon or truck or trailer.

From [Cars and Trucks Word Search](https://books.google.it/books?id=QwpEt9vUgBcC&pg=PA28&dq=%22truck%20bed%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBGoVChMI7oOn1-fDxwIVRloUCh2f7wej#v=onepage&q=%22truck%20bed%22&f=false):

> - At the end of the TRUCK BED, there is a huge METAL flap. The FLAP is only attached on two sides, so it SWINGS open when the truck bed is raised and the load of GRAVEL, or dirt, pushes against it. The WEIGHT of the load opens the flap ...

[image]

[image]

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=truck%20bed&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctruck%20bed%3B%2Cc0): *truck bed*.

Answer (score 1):

it is a truck bed, the term is used [here](http://www.tanksplanesthings.com/tpt/Armor/Kits/15-cwt/15cwt.htm) if you need proof

[image]